# Infinite tetration for complex domain

Tags: complex-analysis, convergence-divergence, exponentiation, tetration

$$f(z)=z^{z^{z^{.^{.}}}}$$
$$for\space z \space \in C\rightarrow C$$

Can we define the range of this function(convergence-divergence specifically) without taking help from fractals? I checked out some articles but I couldn't find any exhaustive theory for the complex domain.
Any help will be appreciated :)

Comment: The question is closely related to the [Lambert W](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function) function, and noted in the [article](https://web.archive.org/web/20101214110615/http://www.apmaths.uwo.ca/~djeffrey/Offprints/W-adv-cm.pdf) referenced there; I would [follow](https://www.fq.math.ca/Scanned/23-2/baker.pdf) the chain (I didn't yet).

Comment: Thanks for the reply, the 'article' you have referenced has some useful information for this question. Thanks again :)